# Cutting / splitting strings with Java

Tags: java

I have a string as follows:

```
2012/02/01,13:27:20,872226816,-1174749184,2136678400,2138578944,-17809408,2147352576
```

I want to extract the number: 872226816, so in this case I assume after the second comma start reading the data and then the following comma end the reading of data.

Example output:

```
872226816
```

Comment: Why not giving it a try yourself and then checking errors on your code? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
s = "2012/02/01,13:27:20,872226816,-1174749184,2136678400,2138578944,-17809408,2147352576";
s.split(",")[2];
```

Javadoc for [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

If the number you want will always be after the 2nd comma, you can do something like so:

```
String str = "2012/02/01,13:27:20,872226816,-1174749184,2136678400,2138578944,-17809408,2147352576";
String[] line = str.split(",");
System.out.println(line[2]);
```