# Splitting strings with Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cutting / splitting strings with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096660/cutting-splitting-strings-with-java)

I have a string e.g.:

```
C:        16896208896
```

How then can I get the following output:

```
16896208896
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at String's javadocs? Was stackoverflow the first place you tried?

Comment: `System.out.println("16896208896");`

Comment: You've asked a very similar question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096660/cutting-splitting-strings-with-java. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and think twice before asking a question on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3):

[Java docs on String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String[] expl = rawString.split(":");
System.out.print(expl[1].trim());
```

Comment: +1: I would use Java 7 Javadoc and a String which ignores white space instead of a char `":\\s+"`

Comment: @usoban,You should really get in the habit of linking the most current javadoc.

Answer (score 3):

```
String str = "C:        16896208896"
str.split("        ")[1];
```

or

```
String str = "C:        16896208896"
str.substring(10);
```

or use regexp to filter out exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`str.split(":")[1].trim()`

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
yourString.split("\\s+")[1];
```

Comment: Actually it is `yourString.split("\\s+")[1];`.

Answer (score 0):

`substring(10)`

To give a better more complete answer we would need more details about the variability of the string.

Comment: this approach is not advisable as a `substring` of a string has the same size as the original string. check string field `value`. check my answers for the generic approach

Comment: Your answer might use less memory but definitely is less efficient from a processing time perspective as well as being less straight-forward. Granted that if the exact starting position of the number is not known, a split would be required.

Comment: yeah i get it. Thats why I said that it is a generic approach. using substring is sort of a hardcoding here

Answer (score 0):

`myStr.split(" ")[1]`

where `myStr = "C:   sdg55253522355345"`

Answer (score 0):

The very simplest way, assuming there are always ten characters before the number starts would be

```
System.out.println(theString.substring(10));
```

If the number of characters varies, then something like

```
System.out.println(theString.split(" ")[1]);
```

would work.

Comment: `System.out.println(theString.split(" ")[1]);` will return a blank space. If the number of characters varies, can't we use something like `System.out.println(theString.split(":")[1].trim());`..?

Answer (score 0):

This gets rid of arbitrary non-numeric characters before and after any number within any string, provided that there is only a single number in the string

```
"C:        16896208896  ".replaceAll("^\\D*(\\d+)\\D*$", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\s*(\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);
matcher.find();
String result = matcher.group(1);
```

Use regular expressions to find what you want. It's the best way to solve your problem if you don't know how many spaces are before the number.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution depends on your string structure: Is it always like in your example? Then you could just take the substring starting at position 2 and trim it (s.substring(2).trim()).

Alternatively, if the portion in front of the ":" varies, split the string at the ":" using split (see http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-split-example).

If there is no fixed delimiter things get more involved. You could use e.g. as suggested before a regular expression to match the numeric part.